# Checking a session on a master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I check a session on a master page?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're looking to do?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have this right, your question is a little short.

You don't check session on the master, you check your session in the controller or higher and then pass a model to the view.

The view data can be grabbed from the master and you can then perform an action based on what is returned.

If this is not what you're after then please post more details on the exact nature of what you are trying to achieve.